# 3D reconstruction from 2D

Tags: image-processing, 3d

I've 2D slices of a 3D micro CT image. The image stack is available in .tif format. 
In the [original study](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-49055-7), 3D reconstruction has been performed using Imaris software. I'd like
to reproduce the results presented in the original paper. However, I don't have a license for Imaris.

I tried to use 3D Slicer which is an open source software. I could load the images, but couldn't generate the 3D volume. I can provide further details if someone has worked on this tool.

I intend to create a 3D volume from the segmented images and filter the skeleton based on its thickness.
Post this, I'd like to delete some branches of the skeleton. For instance, if there are 500 branches, I would like to reduce it by an order of magnitude by deleting branches (selecting a particular region of interest). I'm a beginner in this field and I'm not sure which tool can be used.

Any suggestions on how to proceed will be really helpful.

Comment: If you’re new, maybe ImageJ is the tool for you.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks a lot for the response. I did try ImageJ. The stack in the above-mentioned link has ~1900 images. I could drag and drop the complete folder containing the images. Next, I could also view the animation of all frames. Unfortunately, while trying to use the 3D viewer plug-in, a memory error pops up (I'm using Windows 10, 64-bit). I'm open to suggestions for libraries in MATLAB or Python too.